# How to handle events from ResourceDictionary without using ResourceDictionary Code-Behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, resourcedictionary

I would like help regarding how to handle events from controls in a ResourceDictionary (e.g. Styles.xaml) without using ResourceDictionary Code-Behind (e.g. Styles.xaml.cs), mainly because I want the Styles.xaml to just be there for styling.

My scenario is, I have a Custom Page which uses a ResourceDictionary for DataTemplate styles (I am using a TemplateSelector). However, the problem I am currently having is for handling events. For example:

I have this in my **Styles.xaml**:

```
.
.
<Button Click="Button_Click"/>
.
```

And I declare this in the **CustomPage.xaml.cs** :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  // some code
}
```

However, it does not work. Is there any way to explicitly tell that I want to use that particular Event Handler for the button's click event? Additionally, is it possible to have different handlers for each page e.g.

**CustomPage2.xaml.cs:**

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   // some different code from CustomPage.xaml.cs
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Any errors in the output window?

Comment: Nope. Actually, I'm not looking for correct syntax as those are just simple code snippets. I'm just looking for ways on how to implement it because currently, what I have is not the way and does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple: do not handle events such a way. Use bindings instead (especially, if you're using data templates). E.g., for `Button`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}">
```

where `MyCommand` is a [`ICommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx)-implemented instance from your data context.

If you're not familiar with data bindings in WPF, start read from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx).